# Mismatching return of a query with NamedQuery

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, jpa, named-query

Hi to all i'm new in J2EE world.
 I'm trying to use @Namequery to get a List of String from my model(the class is called Element), in this case the attribute **name**.
Why when I use `@NamedQuery(name="Element.findAllNames",query="SELECT e.name FROM Element e")`
 and I use it on my ElementMgrBean using:

```
public List<String> getAllElementsName() {
    return  em.createNamedQuery(Element.FIND_ALLNAMES,Element.class).getResultList();
}
```

the result appears to be a list of elements instead of a list of String as I expected.
Someone can explain me why Java says: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from List of Element to List of String"??
PS: I have defined:`public static final String FIND_ALLNAMES = "Element.findAllNames";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `em.createNamedQuery("NameOfNamedQuery", MyClass.class)`, you say you want to fetch MyClass instances (in your query MyClass==Element). The problem is now, that your query `SELECT e.name FROM Element e` returns Strings instead of Element instances (as the e.name fields are of type Strings).

In order to correct the problem you either correct the call to `em.createNamedQuery(Element.FIND_ALLNAMES, String.class)` (the preferred solution, as it returns a `TypedQuery<String>` instance), or you remove the second parameter: `em.createNamedQuery(Element.FIND_ALLNAMES)` (in this case you are not type-safe anymore, as it returns a `Query` instance).